# The classification of specific examples of Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I have learned that $\mathbf{C}$ is a parabolic Riemann surface. But I do not know how to show that :

(1) The punctured plane $\mathbf{C}^{*}$ is also a parabolic Riemann surface, but it is not when omits two points of $\mathbf{C}$.

(2)Moreover, if Riemann surface $\mathbf{M}$ is compact, then $$\mathbf{M} \backslash \{p_{1},...,p_{n}\}$$ is the parabolic Riemann surface.

(3)If Riemann surface $\mathbf{M}$, then $$\mathbf{M} \backslash B_{r}(z_{0}) $$ is the hyperbolic Riemann surface.

Comment: For (1), the function $e^z$ is a covering from $\mathbb{C}$ to the punctured plane, but by Picard's theorem, such a covering doesn't exist when we omit two points.

Comment: (3) how to use the $log z$?